# Undefined variable com import python

Tags: python-3.x

Estou tendo problemas com a herança de atributos entre uma classe mãe e uma classe filha que se encontram em dois arquivos diferentes.

Quando as uso no mesmo arquivo não é apresentado nenhum erro:

Arquivo cls_usuario.py:

```
    class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, id_usuario, nome, login, senha, tipo_conta, departamento, cargo, situacao):
        self._id_usuario = id_usuario
        self._nome_usuario = nome
        self._login_usuario = login
        self._senha_usuario = senha
        self._tipo_conta_usuario = tipo_conta 
        self._departamento_usuario = departamento
        self._cargo_usuario = cargo
        self._situacao_usuario = situacao    

class Administrador(cls_usuario.Usuario):
    def __init__(self, id_administrador):
        super().__init__(id_usuario, nome, login, senha, tipo_conta, departamento, cargo, situacao)
        self.id_administrador = id_administrador
```

O problema aparece quando tento separar as duas classes em arquivos diferentes, pois, gostaria de deixar o meu projeto mais organizado, além de, precisar usar a classe mãe em diversas outras classes.

Arquivo cls_usuario.py - versão 2:

```
    class Usuario:
    def __init__(self, id_usuario, nome, login, senha, tipo_conta, departamento, cargo, situacao):
        self._id_usuario = id_usuario
        self._nome_usuario = nome
        self._login_usuario = login
        self._senha_usuario = senha
        self._tipo_conta_usuario = tipo_conta 
        self._departamento_usuario = departamento
        self._cargo_usuario = cargo
        self._situacao_usuario = situacao
```

Arquivo cls_administrador.py:

```
import cls_usuario 

class Administrador(cls_usuario.Usuario):
    def __init__(self, id_administrador):
        #super().__init__(id_usuario, nome, login, senha, tipo_conta, departamento, cargo, situacao)
        self.id_administrador = id_administrador
```

[image: Imagem com os erros exibidos]

Comment: Algo importante para lembrar em python é que arquivos não representam organização. Na grande maioria das vezes separar em arquivos vai mais deixar bagunçado do que organizado. Busque sempre dividir em arquivos quando as responsabilidades dos códigos serem distintas, quando fazem coisas completamente diferentes. Isso é tão verdade na linguagem que é bastante comum você ver bibliotecas inteiras implementadas em apenas um arquivo.

Comment: Sobre o problema, reflita: para criar um usuário eu precisaria informar nome, login, senha, etc. Para criar um administrador eu só precisaria do id. Qual seria o nome deste administrador? Você chamou o método `__init__` passando variáveis que não existem na classe `Administrador`.

Comment: Do jeito qu evocê postou - fora as identações erradas, não vai ocorrer esse erro - suponho que no código que tem esses erros, a sua linha chamando `super` não esteja comentada, certo?  (O serros alias que nem são da linguagem, são de alguma ferramenta de verificação de código - a linguagem daria um NameError na primeira variável inexistente sem indicar as outras)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O problema vai acontecer se estiver assim  -  e não importa se estiver no mesmo arquivo ou não:

```
import cls_usuario 

class Administrador(cls_usuario.Usuario):
    def __init__(self, id_administrador):
        super().__init__(id_usuario, nome, login, senha, tipo_conta, departamento, cargo, situacao)
        self.id_administrador = id_administrador
```

(eu descomentei a primeira linha do `__init__` com a chamada ao `super`).

Bom, os nomes `id_usuario`, `nome`, e os outros argumentos que você quer passar na chamada a superclasse não existem nessa classe filha. Não tem mágica aí - o seu método`__init__` está recebendo apenas o parâmetro `id_administrador`. Ele teria sim acesso às outras informações, como atributos da classe (`self._nome`, etc...) *se* a superclasse fosse inicializada e configurasse esses parâmetros.

Você tem duas opções aí: 
Ou declara todos os parâmetros por extenso na classe filha, declarando os nomes todos no `__init__`:

```
class Administrador(Usuario):
    def __init__(self, id_usuario, nome, login, senha, tipo_conta, departamento, cargo, situacao, id_administrador):
        super().__init__(id_usuario, nome, login, senha, tipo_conta, departamento, cargo, situacao)
        self.id_administrador = id_administrador
```

Ou usa uma assinatura genérica, que recebe qualquer número de argumentos sequênciais, e qualquer número de argumentos com nome, *e* obriga o parâmetro que vocẽ precisa na subclasse, `id_administrador`, a ser enviado com nome - isso é, ele não poderia ser enviado como argumento posicional. Na verdade, para uma classe recebendo tantos parâmetros nem é muito saudável fazer a chamada com argumentos posicionais - o melhor é fazer a chamada sempre com o nome dos parâmetros mesmo, a fim de evitar confusão de posição na hora de digitar, e de tornar possível a verificaçao da ordem. (isso é, instânciar o usuário com uma chamada do tipo:

`u = Usuario(id_usuario=id_usuario, nome=nome, login=login....)` em vez de  `Usuario(id_usuario, nome, login....)`

De qualquer forma, nesse caso você poderia deixar o seu `__init__` da subclasse assim:

```
class Administrador(Usuario):
    def __init__(self, *args, *, id_administrador, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.id_administrador = id_administrador
```

Só mais duas considerações: isso quebraria da mesma forma dentro de um mesmo arquivo -  a não ser que sua identação errada aqui na pergunta seja reflexo de uma identação ainda mais errada no seu código e você declarou a subclasse aninhada dentro do método `__init__` da superclasse (nesse caso os parâmetros seriam visíveis como variáveis "nonlocal").

A segunda: você não deveria indicar que todos esses parâmetros são "privados", ou seja, prefixa-los com "_", a não ser que isso realmente tenha uma utilidade prática. Ao contrário de usar dois `__`, não estaria errado se realmente a intenção for que nenhum código  fora da classe deva ler ou escrever em qualquer um desses atributos, mas mesmo não estando errado, fica estranho.

Comment: Até o momento o seguinte código está resolvendo o meu problema:
class Administrador(Usuario):
    def __init__(self, id_usuario, nome, login, senha, tipo_conta, departamento, cargo, situacao, id_administrador):
        super().__init__(id_usuario, nome, login, senha, tipo_conta, departamento, cargo, situacao)
        self.id_administrador = id_administrador

Porém o exemplo com *args e *kwargs parece ser mais interessante, no entanto, aparece sintaxe inválida. Poderia dar uma explicação mais detalhada?

Comment: A sintaxe daresposta funciona - são dois asteriscos antes do "kwargs" - a explicação detalhada do que eles são pode ser encontrada em outros lugares - vou achar um link e coloco aqui - é melhor  do que re-escrever.